# NSString Backslash escaping

Tags: iphone, xml, nsstring, backslash

I am working on an iPhone OS application that sends an xml request to a webservice. In order to send the request, the xml is added to an NSString. When doing this I have experienced some trouble with quotation marks `"` and backslashes `\` in the xml file, which have required escaping. Is there a complete list of characters that need to be escaped?

Also, is there an accepted way of doing this escaping (ie replacing `\` with `\\` and `"` with `\"`) or is it a case of creating a method myself?

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Why do you have to escape characters?

Comment: Hi Nikolai, this was nearly three years ago. I needed to escape the characters to form valid xml. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString *escapedString = [unescapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"];
escapedString = [escapedString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
```

Doesn't fully answer your question, but seems like it might help with the second part...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a NSScanner that will scan for characters from a character set and if found, it will add the escaping `\\` to a new string and copy the next substring from the found special character till the next.

```
NSString *sourceString = /* Some input String*/;
NSMutableString *destString = [@"" mutableCopy];
NSCharacterSet *escapeCharsSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ()\\"];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:sourceString];
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    NSString *tempString;
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:escapeCharsSet intoString:&tempString];
    if([scanner isAtEnd]){
        [destString appendString:tempString];
    }
    else {
        [destString appendFormat:@"%@\\%@", tempString, [sourceString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([scanner scanLocation], 1)]];
        [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
    }
}
```