# in objective-c is there any easy way to add backslash in front of special characters?

Tags: objective-c, nsfilemanager, nstask

**Note: Not sure why this is marked as duplicate as I clearly stated that I don't want to use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString over and over again.**

I have a question regarding the special character filename.

I have implemented a program, so that when you open a file or multiple files, the program will read all these filenames and local path and store them into the NSMutableArray. This part works perfectly without a problem.

My program also need to use NSTask to manipulate these files. However, the problem is, sometimes filename will contain special characters, for example,  `/Users/josh/Desktop/Screen Shot 2013-03-19 at 2.05.06 PM.png`.

I have to replace space with backslash and space

```
NSString *urlPath = [[self url] path];
urlPath = [urlPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"\\("];
urlPath = [urlPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@"\\)"];
urlPath = [urlPath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"\\ "];
```

to: `/Users/josh/Desktop/Screen\ Shot\ 2013-03-19\ at\ 2.05.06\ PM.png`

so that I can manipulate the file properly.

Same for the `(` and `)`. I also need to add backslash before that.

but there are too many special characters. ie.

```
/Users/josh/Desktop/~!@#$?:<,.>%^&*()_+`-={}[]\|'';.txt
```

I need to change to:

```
/Users/josh/Desktop/\~\!@\#\$\?\:\<\,.\>\%^\&\*\(\)_+\`-\=\{\}\[\]\\\|\'\'\;.txt
```

and not to mention other special characters (ie. accent)

**Is there any easy way to put a backslash in front of each special character, as I don't want to keep calling `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` over and over again.**

Comment: Based on this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2931942/nsstring-backslash-escaping it would appear thats one of the best methods around at the moment :/

Comment: Can you give an example of what type of commands you want to run in the `NSTask`? There should be no need to escape anything in file paths as they are normally handed directly as `argv` and undergo no shell espansion.

Comment: @NSGod I always thought that escape is needed. ie. if you open the terminal and drag a file which the filename contains a special code, terminal will automatically add the escape backslash. this is how i found out ie. /Users/josh/Desktop/~!@#$?:<,.>%^&*()_+`-={}[]\|'';.txt

I need to change to: /Users/josh/Desktop/\~!@#\$\?\:\<\,.>\%^\&*()_+`-\={}[]\\|\'\'\;.txt

Comment: @rmaddy this is not duplicate. I was asking if there is any other way beside using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString over and over again.

Comment: @Josh NSGod is right. The need for escaping arises from the shell (for instance bash). `NSTask` does not use a shell. If you would escape the paths nobody would unescape them and the files would not be found.

Comment: @Josh It is a duplicate question. Both questions ask how to add backslashes to a bunch of characters. Just because you don't like one of the answers doesn't mean it's not a duplicate. Make that big ugly answer into a helpful category method on NSString. Then you get a nice simple way to do what you want.

Comment: I think this question's gist is about how to escape strings for use as an argument to the bash. That's a different use case than the one in the marked-as-duplicate post. So I vote against duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in `NSTask`'s documentation for the [`setArguments:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTask/setArguments%3a) method, there should be no need to do special quoting:

> **Discussion**
>
> The `NSTask` object converts both *path* and the strings in
>   *arguments* to appropriate C-style strings (using
>   fileSystemRepresentation) before passing them to the task via `argv[]`.
>   The strings in *arguments* do not undergo shell expansion, so you do not
>   need to do special quoting, and shell variables, such as `$PWD`, are not
>   resolved.

If you feel it is necessary, can you please provide some examples of the commands you want to run in the `NSTask`?

[UPDATE]: I see in the comments that you indeed are using the `NSTask` to execute a `bash` shell with `-c`, which I had wondered about. I've generally used `NSTask` to execute the command directly rather than going through the shell, like this:

```
NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/ls"];
[task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-l", self.url.path, nil]];
```

Can you give a more accurate example of the actual command you want to run? For example, are you piping a series of commands together? Perhaps there might be an alternate way to achieve the same results without the need for using the `bash` shell...

Comment: NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/bash"];
    NSString *argument = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ls -l %@", self.url.path];
    [task setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-c", argument, nil]];

Comment: so if I just pass self.url.path without adding backslash, it won't work. But as I said there are too many characters need to add backslash and keep using stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString seems not efficient

Comment: A better solution would be not to use the shell. Why not "/bin/ls" as launch path and ["-l", self.url.path] as launch arguments?

Comment: I remember reading an article from stackoverflow.com that, use /bin/bash if the NSTask has too many arguments. ie. | grep or | awk. That's why I use /bin/bash here. Some of the argument of my NSTask is short (ie. ls -l) but some involves grep and awk.

Comment: I guess I will use a few NSTask instead of using bash. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to use an `NSRegularExpressionSearch` search.

It would look something like this

```
+ (NSString *) addBackslashes: (NSString *) string
{
    // First convert the name string to a pure ASCII string
    NSData *asciiData = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *asciiString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:asciiData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] lowercaseString];

    // Define the characters that we will replace
    NSString *searchCharacters = @"PUT IN ALL OF YOUR SPECIAL CHARACTERS HERE";
    // example NSString *searchCharacters = @"!@#$%&*()";

    // replace them
    NSString *regExPattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[%@]", searchCharacters];

    string = [asciiString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:regExPattern withString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\\%@", regExPattern] options:NSRegularExpressionSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, asciiString.length)];
    return string;
}
```

Comment: using regular expression is also a good way, it's much clearer than calling stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString numerous times, thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could maintain a set of strings that need to be escaped and use NSScanner to build the new string by iterating the the source string and each time a problematic character is found u first add `\\` to a destination string and continue coping the next chars.

```
NSString *sourceString = @"/Users/josh/Desktop/\"Screen Shot\" 2013-03-19 at 2\\05\\06 PM.png";
NSMutableString *destString = [@"" mutableCopy];
NSCharacterSet *escapeCharsSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" ()\\"];

NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:sourceString];
while (![scanner isAtEnd]) {
    NSString *tempString;
    [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:escapeCharsSet intoString:&tempString];
    if([scanner isAtEnd]){
        [destString appendString:tempString];
    }
    else {
        [destString appendFormat:@"%@\\%@", tempString, [sourceString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange([scanner scanLocation], 1)]];
        [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
    }
}

NSLog(@"\n%@\n%@", sourceString, destString);
```

result:

```
/Users/josh/Desktop/Screen Shot 2013-03-19 at 2.05.06 PM.png
/Users/josh/Desktop/Screen\ Shot\ 2013-03-19\ at\ 2.05.06\ PM.png
```